# Using $or and $ne Operators Together in MongoDB Query

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to run a MongoDB query to return all documents that don't match one value OR another. After consulting the documentation, I see this example:

```
{ $or: [ { quantity: { $lt: 20 } }, { price: 10 } ] }
```

So this is what I tried:

```
{ $or:  [ { paymentType: { $ne: "full" } }, { $ne: "partial" } ] }
```

This results in an error:

> 'unknown top level operator: $ne'

I also tried this:

```
{ $or:  [ { paymentType: { $ne: "full" } }, { paymentType: { $ne: "partial" }} ] }
```

... but this simply returns all documents, with no filtering done on the "paymentType" property.

What's the correct syntax here?

Comment: Use `$nin` for match on single field. Something like `{paymentType:{$nin:["full", "partial"]}}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to a commenter for pointing out that I could either use `$nin` or `$and` but not `$or`. Another option, which I find the most intuitive in this particular case, is the `$nor` operator, like so:

```
{ $nor:  [ { paymentType: { $ne: "full" } }, { paymentType: { $ne: "partial" }} ] }
```

This will return all documents that don't match either of these values.

Answer (score 2):

Your third version of code syntax is correct.

But the logic seems wrong.

Your query translated to:

```
paymentType != full or paymentType != partial
```

This actually always hold true, (since one `paymentType` value cannot be `full` and `partial` at the same time.)

**Update**

> To clarify, what I'm trying to query -- in plain English -- is to return all results where "paymentType" is not "full" or "partial".

In this case you should use `$and` instead. or `$nin` is also good.

Remember this law:

```
not (p or q) <=> (not p) and (not q)
```

Comment: To clarify, what I'm trying to query -- in plain English -- is to return all results where "paymentType" is not "full" or "partial".

Comment: Then use must use an `$and` instead. Or use `$nin` like suggested above

Comment: This is probably the way to go, as suggested above: {paymentType:{$nin:["full", "partial"]}}

Comment: Good point. If I were to use an operator here, it should be $and, not $or.

Comment: Actually, even better is this, the $nor operator:
{ $nor:  [ { paymentType: { $ne: "full" } }, { paymentType: { $ne: "partial" }} ] }

Comment: Your usecase is completely different than the example :D

Comment: How so? You may be misunderstanding my usecase.

Comment: In my opinion $nin is the way to go in MongoDB.

Comment: Because? What's your reasoning? Why do you think that's the superior choice in all such cases?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find `all` documents which do not match those two values only why don't you simply change the `$or` to `$and`? Easiest and shortest is to use the `$nin` as already suggested but not sure why complicate it with `$nor`/`$or` etc.

```
{ $and:  [ { paymentType: { $ne: "full" } }, { paymentType: { $ne: "partial" }} ] }
```

will select all documents that don't match either of these values. It reads and understands much easier then the double negation you end up with `$nor` no?

It says give me all paymentTypes which are not `full` and not `partial`. Same if you use the `$nin`.

Comment: I guess it's partly a subjective preference. For me, mentally, $nor equates more closely with the logic in my mind in this case than $and -- hence why I made the mistake in using $or instead of $and to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

As per the plain english understanding, you should use

```
{ $nor:  [ { paymentType: "full" }, { paymentType:  "partial"} ] }
```

This is the modification to @Muirik's answer as it didn't work for me as you are already using `$nor`. Thus, you should not use `$ne` inside.

Thanks.